# How to get Sinatra on stage with XP?

Tags: sinatra

Keen to try Sinatra but I’m using Windows XP and getting error:

“C:/Ruby19/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:in `remove_const’: constant URI::WFKV_ not defined (NameError)”

There is a reference to the problem at: https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/247
where Shanev removed the fix but how do I do that??

Comment: Same behaviour on Windows XP for me on Rack 1.3.**4**, but it's gone after upgrading to Rack 1.3.**5**. Can you provide a minimal app to reproduce it?

Comment: Basics.rb:                                                   require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra' 
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end

Comment: Well, that's weird. What versions of Sinatra and Rack do you think you're using?

Comment: Ok, no idea then. I just tested with Sinatra 1.3.0 and Rack 1.3.5 without getting any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to with ruby 1.9.1 update your ruby version and then check.
Ref:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990447/ruby-sinatra-hello-world-error-in-remove-const-constant-uriwfkv-not-define)

Comment: I reverted to Rack 1.3.4 and got past original error. Now I get HTTP 500 internal server error:

Comment: INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1380 port=4567
ERROR NameError: uninitialized constant Rack::Builder::FrameOptions   Can you point me to instructions on how to update to 1.9.2 on XP?

Comment: Install ruby version manager, and do spend some time on figuring how to manage ruby version and bundler gemsets will save u a lot of time in the future

Comment: Thanks for advice. I've set up Ubuntu,installed 1.9.2 via RVM, and Sinatra worked first time!!