# Ruby Sinatra Hello World Error in `remove_const': constant URI::WFKV_ not defined (NameError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Just trying to get simple http server running and have no clue about ruby

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:in `remove_const': constant URI::WFKV_ not defined (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53:in `<module:URI>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:12:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/request.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/request.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/showexceptions.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/showexceptions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:12:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra/base.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra.rb:4:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.1/lib/sinatra.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from http.rb:1:in `require'
    from http.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

and here is my version of ruby on centos 
`ruby 1.9.1p376 (2009-12-07 revision 26041) [x86_64-linux]`

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Please provide the contents of your code causing this error. Ideally, keep deleting code (as long as this error still occurs) until you get close to the minimum number of lines of code needed to reproduce.

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce with the following code: `require 'sinatra'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's known issue specific for ruby-1.9.1 and rake-1.3.5. Please look at [this](https://github.com/rack/rack/pull/247). What about updating ruby for 1.9.2 or 1.9.3 version?

**UPDATE**

On the one hand, WFKV_ constant was absent in ruby 1.9.1 version and appears in 1.9.2 version.  On the other hand, this constant is defined in rack's uri/common_192.rb file. 2011-10-03 Ben Hamill fixed issue #246 'Silence the warning about redefining this constant from the standard library' through addition `remove_const :WFKV_` line of code and this fix was included in rack-1.3.5 version. Therefore, if you use 1.9.1 version, you have to use rack-1.3.4.

Comment: ill look though this and see if updates fix it... i used the rpm so i may compile from source